# convert from IIS rewrite to nginx

Tags: nginx, iis-7, rewrite

I need to convert an IIS rewrite rule to NGinX rewrite.
I made a small progress because I don´t know how to convert parts of IIS rules.  Here is my IIS config:

- Matches the Pattern: ^(.*)$
- Rerite URL: index.html and append Query String
- Conditions: Match All

  - REQUEST_URI does not matches the Pattern "/api(.*)$ ignoring case"
  - REQUEST_FILENAME is not a file

So far what I did on NGinX was

```
location / {
    root   html;
    index  index.html index.htm;
    if ($request_uri !~ "/api(.*)$")
    {
      rewrite ^(.*)$ index.html
    }
}
```

I think I must use the variable $request_filename however I don´t know how to use it to filter files like on IIS and put it inside the if condition in an AND logical operation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a typical case of front-controller pattern, and that is implemented in nginx like this:

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html$is_args$args;
}
```

This will make nginx first look for files, and if a file is not found, then it sends the request to `/index.html` and appends possible query arguments.

Then you specify different rules for your `/api` URI:

```
location /uri {
    ... API handling rules ...
}
```

Without further information this is the most I can write as an answer.